# RandomizedSearchCV - problem with param_distrubitions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I'm doing a fit on RandomizedSearchCV, this is my pipeline and param_grid

I'm passing this as the estimator:

```
pipe_rand_svc=MyPipeline(steps=[('standardscaler',StandardScaler()),
                                ('randsc',RandomizedSearchCV(SVC(probability=True),
                         param_grid))])
```

I'm passing this as the param_distributions

```
param_grid={'randsc__estimator__C':[1E-2,1E-1,1,10,100],'randsc__estimator__gamma':[1E-2,1E-1,1,10,100]}
```

the above are the names that I got from running

```
pipe_rand_svc.get_params().keys()
```

yet I still get this error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter randsc for estimator SVC(C=1, break_ties=False, cache_size=200, class_weight=None,
    coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3,
    gamma=1, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=True,
    random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Would appreciate any advice!

EDIT:

smaple code:

```
X1,y1=make_classification()
param_grid={'C':[1E-2,1E-1,1,10,100],'gamma':[1E-2,1E-1,1,10,100]}
pipe_rand_svc=MyPipeline(steps=[('standardscaler',StandardScaler()),('randsc',RandomizedSearchCV(SVC(probability=True),param_grid))])
a=RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe_rand_svc,param_distributions=param_grid)
a=a.fit(X1,y1)
```

EDIT2:

curiously, this works like a charm:

```
param_grid={'svc__C':[1E-2,1E-1,1,10,100],'svc__gamma':[1E-2,1E-1,1,10,100]}
pipe_svc=MyPipeline(steps=[('standardscaler',StandardScaler()),('svc',SVC(probability=True))])
b=GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_svc,param_grid=param_grid)
b=b.fit(X1,y1)
```

EDIT3:

right, I see what I've done. passed RandomizedSearchCV into the pipeline and then tried to run RandomizedSearchCV again... Apologies for everyone involved. Sleep depravation is taking it's toll.

Comment: why do you have ```randsc__estimator__``` before each parameter?

Comment: That's what the keys are.  People that had issues with the same error message usually did not use the keys as parameter names (there'a a lot of questions regarding this error message, and using the keys is usually the suggested fix. Does not work for me though).

Comment: Please use some dummy data (say with scikit-learn [`make_classification`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html)) to post a [MCVE]; it's difficult to debug with the piece-meal info you provide here.

Comment: Sure thing, just did that, make_classification is pretty convenient!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just removing the `randsc__estimator__` prefix? I tried to run your code (with some modifications) and it worked without the prefix.

```
param_grid={'C':[1E-2,1E-1,1,10,100],'gamma':[1E-2,1E-1,1,10,100]}
```

From the perspective of the object instance `pipe_rand_svc`, it does have a pipeline object named `randsc` with contains a `RandomizedSearchCV` with an estimator `estimator` that takes a parameter `C`, so `randsc__estimator__C` makes sense.

However, if you look at just this:

```
RandomizedSearchCV(SVC(probability=True), param_grid))
```

when `RandomizedSearchCV` is being instantiated, it doesn't know or care that it's in a pipeline. From its perspective, it's dealing directly with the `SVC` classifier so the params dictionary only needs to use the names of the classifier's hyperparameters, e.g.: `C` and `gamma`.

If, on the other hand, you were passing, say, a pipeline into `RandomizedSearchCV` (instead of just a classifier), then you'd need the more specific syntax. For example:

```
params_C = numpy.linspace(0, 2, 40)

ppl = Pipeline([('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                ('classifier', LogisticRegression(max_iter=500))])

gs = GridSearchCV(ppl,
                  param_grid={'classifier__C': params_C},
                  cv=KFold(10, shuffle=True))
```

Here, I'm passing a pipeline into `GridSearchCV` so now I need to be more specific about which parameters I'm referring to.

There are some special cases where you need to use `estimator__`. For example, if your classifier were wrapped in a `OneVsRestClassifier`, `estimator` would refer to the `OneVsRestClassifier` instance and you'd refer to the `C` hyperparameter of the `SVC` instance like this:

```
ppl = Pipeline([('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(verbose=True)))])
GridSearchCV(ppl, {'clf__estimator__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1]})
```

Comment: Just posted sample code, changing to 'C' and 'gamma' doesn't do the trick. I'm reallty stumbling in the dark here, but maybe this'll help: I tried the same setup with GridSearchCV and pipe_svc=MyPipeline(steps=[('standardscaler',StandardScaler()),('svc',SVC(probability=True))]) and had no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

So general take-away is that it is indeed the right solution to use parameter names from `pipeline.get_params().keys()` as `grid_params`. The question is a result of my monsterous mistake, not sure if I should delete it (redundant - several questions already asked on the topic, I thought this was a different case but turns out it was just my mistake in a different part of the code).